# Jest testing Axios cancel request Issue with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs

In my code I am trying to cancel an axios request within my app, following the [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation). So there is no error on compiling the code and no errors in the console.

However when I am trying to mock Axios in Jest and create a mock function and file with axios.js in the **mock** folder, In my test suite I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
```

I have don the following in my app:

```
 const cancelRequest = axios.CancelToken.source();

      search = query => {
      axios
        .get (`https://www.url.com?s=${query}` , {
        cancelToken: cancelRequest.token
        })
        .then (response => {
        this.setState ( {array: response.data.data, loading: false});
        })
        .catch (error => {
        console.log ('Error', error);
        });
      };

      componentWillUnmount() {
        cancelRequest.cancel();
      }
```

Any Idea's

Comment: How did you mock `axios` package?

Comment: in mocks folder - axios.js > `export default {
  get: jest.fn ().mockResolvedValue ({data: {}}),
};
`